# Where does Google Cloud Storage look for files?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to understand `bucket.upload()`, using the example code in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#upload). It's supposed to upload a file from my computer's local directory to Firebase Cloud Storage:

```
exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Storage_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
  const storage = new Storage();
  const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');

  bucket.upload('./hello_world.ogg', function(err, file, apiResponse) {

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log("No error.");
      }
  });
});
```

The error message is `ENOENT: no such file or directory`. I can see the file in my app's root directory on my computer's hard drive. The file is 12 KB. Why can't Google Cloud Functions find the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my file `hello_world.ogg` from the project root to the `functions` subdirectory. This time I got back `No error`. I'll explore this further...